# How can I kill a process like Process-Hacker does

Tags: kill

When I look for answers this many times and all the answers I have found just say use "taskkill /IM /F"

But that doesn't work when you get access denied from a system process.

How can I kill a process that gives me an access denied error when I try to kill it?

I know there is a way, because I can kill the process with one click in Process-Hacker.

How can Process-Hacker kill the process with no problems? Is this just some function in the Process-Hacker source code that I could re-create in my own program?

Yes, the process I'm trying to kill is an anti-virus process, for what its worth its not for anything malicious. I just need a way of removing an old anti-virus program from 150 computers in order to install another anti-virus software. And I cant uninstall the anti-virus unless I kill this process.

Comment: Is the process in question a service? Which product? I assume it's probably a protected process?  Under the service key for the service, does it have a LaunchProtected DWORD i in the same wasy as Defender does - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinDefend`?  Process Hacker users a number of techniques, it also has a driver it installs which provides other options to say a user mode process such as taskkill.

Comment: Yes it seems like it is a service. Its Webroot. Yes, it is protected (NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, ACCEPTS_PRESHUTDOWN) and no there is no LaunchProtected  DWORD in the registry